# Print list of lists in an 'elegant' way

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list of lists:

```
poster = [[1,  'Col',  1, 28, 29, 30, 19,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [2,  'Col',  1, 31, 32, 33, 22,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [3,  'Col',  1, 34, 35, 36, 25,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [4,  'Col',  2, 19, 20, 21, 10,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [5,  'Col',  2, 22, 23, 24, 13,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [6,  'Col',  2, 25, 26, 27, 16,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [7,  'Col',  3, 10, 11, 12,  1,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [8,  'Col',  3, 13, 14, 15,  4,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [9,  'Col',  3, 16, 17, 18,  7,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [10, 'Row',  1, 19, 20, 21, 22,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3777.5121428571438, 0],
          [11, 'Row',  1, 22, 23, 24, 25,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [12, 'Row',  2, 10, 11, 12, 13,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7555.0242857142875, 0],
          [13, 'Row',  2, 13, 14, 15, 16,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0],
          [14, 'Row',  3,  1,  2,  3,  4,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11332.536428571431, 0],
          [15, 'Row',  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0]]
```

What I want is to print it on the screen in the following format:

```
[[ 1, 'Col',  1, 28, 29, 30, 19,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 2, 'Col',  1, 31, 32, 33, 22,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 3, 'Col',  1, 34, 35, 36, 25,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 4, 'Col',  2, 19, 20, 21, 10,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 5, 'Col',  2, 22, 23, 24, 13,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 6, 'Col',  2, 25, 26, 27, 16,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 7, 'Col',  3, 10, 11, 12,  1,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 8, 'Col',  3, 13, 14, 15,  4,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [ 9, 'Col',  3, 16, 17, 18,  7,      0,     0,     0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [10, 'Row',  1, 19, 20, 21, 22,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3777.5121428571438,   0],
 [11, 'Row',  1, 22, 23, 24, 25,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [12, 'Row',  2, 10, 11, 12, 13,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7555.0242857142875,   0],
 [13, 'Row',  2, 13, 14, 15, 16,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0],
 [14, 'Row',  3,  1,  2,  3,  4,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11332.536428571431,   0],
 [15, 'Row',  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  -3660, -1500, -6792,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                  0,   0]]
```

I have tried with a liner, I have succeeded but above all I am looking for it to be ordered, that is, for the columns to be aligned, since in this case this list of lists is large.

```
print('\n'.join(', '.join(map(str,sl)) for sl in poster))
```

Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried the `pprint` module?

Comment: I have not tried that module, but I am going to check thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to to that is to load in into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(poster)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   1   Col     1   28  29  30  19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
1   2   Col     1   31  32  33  22  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
2   3   Col     1   34  35  36  25  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
3   4   Col     2   19  20  21  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
4   5   Col     2   22  23  24  13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
5   6   Col     2   25  26  27  16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
6   7   Col     3   10  11  12  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
7   8   Col     3   13  14  15  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
8   9   Col     3   16  17  18  7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
9   10  Row     1   19  20  21  22  -3660   -1500   -6792   0   0   0   0   0   3777.512143     0
10  11  Row     1   22  23  24  25  -3660   -1500   -6792   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
11  12  Row     2   10  11  12  13  -3660   -1500   -6792   0   0   0   0   0   7555.024286     0
12  13  Row     2   13  14  15  16  -3660   -1500   -6792   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
13  14  Row     3   1   2   3   4   -3660   -1500   -6792   0   0   0   0   0   11332.536429    0
14  15  Row     3   4   5   6   7   -3660   -1500   -6792   0   0   0   0   0   0.000000    0
```

To print without the row and column headers, use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(poster)
print(df.to_string(index=False , header=False))
```

Output:

```
  1  Col  1  28  29  30  19     0     0     0  0  0  0  0  0      0.000000  0
  2  Col  1  31  32  33  22     0     0     0  0  0  0  0  0      0.000000  0
  3  Col  1  34  35  36  25     0     0     0  0  0  0  0  0      0.000000  0
  4  Col  2  19  20  21  10     0     0     0  0  0  0  0  0      0.000000  0
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use `print(repr(poster[i][j].rjust())`
I would encourage you to read about it at [this link to the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

This implementation will only be printing the array (poster) to your terminal. To turn it into new_array with the correct justification, just replace the print statement.

First you need to make a copy of the array poster and transpose it:
(This will enable you to find the max length of each position of the array)

```
transpose = list(zip(*poster))
```

Then, since there is a string ('Col', 'Row') in your data, you will need to account for it when finding the max length at each position:
(Usig max(lst) won't help because one of your values is a string)

```
def find_abs_max_value(lst):
    max_value = max(lst)
    try:
        min_value = abs(min(lst))
    except TypeError:
        return max_value

    if max_value > min_value:
        return max_value
    else:
        return min_value
```

Then you can just do the following, and get your array!
Here you go:

```
for i in range(len(poster)):
    for j in range(len(poster[i])):
        print(repr(poster[i][j]).rjust(len(str(find_abs_max_value(tranpose[j]))) + 1), end=', ')
    print('\n')
```

What you see above, it an implementation of repr(lst).rjust(some_length). What 'rjust' does is to right-justify each data in your arrray. Hope this was useful!